# Проблема с innerHTML в JS:(

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно изменить обе строки в html, но с помощью innerHTML получается изменить лишь одну строку (ту, где единица написана).

Как можно решить эту проблему?
html:

```
<h2 id='exp'>1</h2><br/>
<h2 id='exp'>2</h2><br/>
```

js:

```
var exp = document.getElementById('exp');<br/>
exp.innerHTML = "Привет!";
```

Comment: Никто не сказал сути: `.getElementById()` всегда берёт только один элемент со страницы с указанным id. Если элементов с одинаковым id несколько, то возьмётся только первый. Из за этого ваша проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно либо изменить id у второй строки и использовать ещё один вызов `getElementById`, либо использовать `getElementsByTagName`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = 'Hello';
}
```

```html
<h2>1</h2>
<h2>2</h2>
```

Но, конечно, лучше не использовать одинаковый `id` у элементов, т. к. это не совсем корректно. Использование `getElementsByTagName` также таит в себе подводные камни (вдруг на странице будут ещё `h2`).

Вероятно, самым правильным способом будет использование `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('exp');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = 'Hello';
}
```

```html
<h2 class='exp'>1</h2>
<h2 class='exp'>2</h2>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое:)

Comment: id должен быть уникальным, если стилизуете элементы это стоит делать классами

Comment: Можно просто getElementsByName при <h2 name='exp'></h2>. Одинаковые name не запрещены, за исключением разве что форм, которые будут передаваться на сервер

Comment: Всем спасибо большое за помощь:) @Regent галочку поставил:)